# Нужно установить v8, а потом v8js

Tags: v8

Как установить V8. Понимаю что много инфы, но мне именно нужен v8, а потом уже v8js. Так-как v8js не работает без v8. как???

Comment: куда Вы пытаетесь его поставить и что с ним будете делать?

Comment: @KoVadim на сервер, генерить блоки и выдавать Ajax-ом

Comment: Может Вы просто nodejs хотите поставить?